# WebGL & Three.js - Render a scene successively in two renderers

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to render a scene in two different renderers (**successively not at the same time**) but it leads to the error "GL_INVALID_OPERATION".

Here is a sample script:

```
var scene1   = new THREE.Scene();
var camera1  = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( ... );
var renderer1= new THREE.WebGLRenderer( ... );

var renderer2= new THREE.WebGLRenderer( ... );
var camera2  = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( ... );

//Render scene1 in renderer1
renderer1.render( scene1, camera1 );

//[After some user event...]
//Render scene1 in renderer2
renderer2.render( scene1, camera2 );  //This fails. getError()=1282 (i.e. GL_INVALID_OPERATION)
```

I know it often deprecated to render a scene in two different renderers even not at the same time, but I could think of no other way of solving my issue as it is part of a very big project.

I understand there are GL data associated to scene1 that are linked to renderer1 but how can I remove those data so that I could render the scene1 again in an other renderer ???

Beware that I am not trying to render the scene in the two renderes simutaneously (which is different than https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/189).

Thanks for the help.
Regards.

Comment: I think you should be more precise on what you want to achieve instead of showing your problem. Also see the examples on how to achieve a renderloop. I am not sure about your problem because it is possible to have 2 renderers and cameras and stuff. Maybe check out the "multiple view" examples that come with three.js

Comment: Hello GuyGood, thanks for your help. However my issue is very different from what you understood. I want to render scene1 successively in renderer1 and then in renderer2.

Comment: I tried to improve the description of my questions I hope this is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to objects/material/textures being bound to specific OpenGL buffers. The solution is thus to unbind from any buffer all the children of the object to be removed from a specific scene, before adding it to an other scene.

I'll post the code of my solution asap.
Regards.